# How to check if there is any memory leak in application by using .Net memory profiler report?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-profiling

As this is my first post on this group so looking for your kind help. Please ignore my mistakes and help me to make it better.

I'm using .net memory profiler to monitor if there is any memory leak in my application.

To analyze the memory leak and usage I ran the application and attached the process with .Net Memory Profiler. Now I opened real time tab and found that

1) Bytes in All Heap is showing up and down graph.
2) Allocated Bytes started from some point and then returned to 0.
3) Gen 0 and 2 Collection values are increasing.

Now I've few questions which I would like to know:
a) As allocated Bytes are returning back to 0 what does it means? Does it mean that there is no memory leak?
b) Why Gen 0 and 2 values are increasing whenever i run the application and not decreasing?
c) What does it mean by Bytes in All Heap?

I tried to search answer of these questions at many sites including .net memory profiler but didn't find answer. I looked into some YouTube videos as well but that also didn't help me.

[image]

As I'm new to **.Net** memory profiler I'm stuck here and not able to proceed please help.

Thanks

Comment: This is the first link  I get on google, pretty useful too: https://memprofiler.com/find-memory-leaks

Answer (score 0):

memory profiling is about counting how many objects are alive in the memory.

> b) Why Gen 0 and 2 values are increasing whenever i run the application and not decreasing?

it means that objects are referenced by something and is not garbage collected.

You have to take `memory snapshot` (one after another in some period) and check the snapshot diff. The diff has to show are object count increased or not. Also you will see what kind of objects are stored in the memory nad try to guess how those objects are created by code you are profiling and why they are not collected.

[Here is more about snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage-without-debugging2?view=vs-2019). It can be applied (in generally) for any profiler

Comment: Thanks but still my query is as it is  As allocated Bytes are returning back to 0 in attached image then what does it means? Does it mean that there is no memory leak?
Also what  is difference between memory leak and memory allocation are they different or same?
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user071992 memeory allocation is done to get memory for new objects. It is ok to have memory allocated for new objects and released if objects are not used any more. Garbage collector is responsible for counting references to created objects and releasing memory that occupied by objects are not used any more. GC is running periodically and uses Gen0, 1, 2 collections to sort objects are not released.